# recyclerview cast exception?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am developing cv android using `RecyclerView OnBindViewHolder` method.

I cannot cast `activity.drawer.navigation.com.kitabsawticlone.EducationAdapter$UniversityViewHolder` to `activity.drawer.navigation.com.kitabsawticlone.EducationAdapter.EducationViewHolder`

Below my Adapter class:

```
public class EducationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {


    public Context context;
    public List<Education> educationList;


    private EducationItem educationItem;

    public static class EducationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView duration, institution, degree;


        public EducationViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            duration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
            institution = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.institution);
            degree = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.degree);


        }
    }

    public static class SubjectViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView subjectImage;
        public TextView subjects;

        public SubjectViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            subjectImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectImage);
            subjects = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjects);


        }
    }

    public static class UniversityViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView icon;
        public TextView item;

        public UniversityViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            item = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);


        }
    }


    public EducationAdapter(List<Education> educationList, EducationItem educationItem, Context context) {

        this.educationList = educationList;
        this.context = context;

        this.educationItem = educationItem;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;
        switch (viewType) {

            case INTERNET_TYPE:
                itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.education_item, parent, false);


                return new EducationViewHolder(itemView);

            case SUBJECT_TYPE:
                itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.subject, parent, false);


                return new SubjectViewHolder(itemView);
            case UNIVERSITY_TYPE:
                itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.subject_list, parent, false);
                return new UniversityViewHolder(itemView);


        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {


                return educationList.get(position).type;
        }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return educationList.size();
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Education education = educationList.get(position);
        if (education != null) {
            switch (education.type()) {
                case Education.INTERNET_TYPE:
                    ((EducationViewHolder) holder).duration.setText(education.getDuration());
                    ((EducationViewHolder) holder).degree.setText(education.getDegree());
                    ((EducationViewHolder) holder).institution.setText(education.getInstitution());
                    break;


                case Education.SUBJECT_TYPE:
                    ((SubjectViewHolder) holder).subjects.getContext().getString(R.string.university_subject);
                    ((SubjectViewHolder) holder).subjectImage.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.university_subjects);
                    break;


                case Education.UNIVERSITY_TYPE:
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        (( UniversityViewHolder) holder).icon.setImageResource(education.image);
                    }
                    ((UniversityViewHolder) holder).item.setText(education.words);


                    break;

            }
        }


    }
}
```

I have checked all of method it seems working fine.

Screenshot in debug mode:

[image: screenshot in debugmode]

Comment: Post the code of `Education` please.

Comment: @earthw0rmjim, https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kyodgorbek/441864cbad718085e3ae81b11ae9bd04/raw/d2a2cc45dc29a64c210935afe9f1460de15f796b/Education.java this Education.java file I cannot add to editor this code thats I am posting gist code

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the error is in these lines:

```
case Education.INTERNET_TYPE:
    ((EducationViewHolder) holder).duration.setText(education.getDuration());
    ((EducationViewHolder) holder).degree.setText(education.getDegree());
    ((EducationViewHolder) holder).institution.setText(education.getInstitution());
    break;
```

Here you are typecasting `holder` to `EducationViewHolder`.  
If the actual type of `holder` is `UniversityViewHolder` then the casting cannot succeed.  
**Edit**: there must be a problem with the items in your list and what they represent to you.  
After this line:

```
Education education = educationList.get(position);
```

you obtain `education.type()` and in the `switch` block you are trying to typecast `EducationViewHolder` to `UniversityViewHolder` but this fails! 
Since you already have defined `getItemViewType()` use this method and try again with the below code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType(position)) {
        case Education.INTERNET_TYPE:
            ((EducationViewHolder) holder).duration.setText(education.getDuration());
            ((EducationViewHolder) holder).degree.setText(education.getDegree());
            ((EducationViewHolder) holder).institution.setText(education.getInstitution());
            break;

        case Education.SUBJECT_TYPE:
            ((SubjectViewHolder) holder).subjects.getContext().getString(R.string.university_subject);
            ((SubjectViewHolder) holder).subjectImage.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.university_subjects);
            break;

        case Education.UNIVERSITY_TYPE:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                ((UniversityViewHolder) holder).icon.setImageResource(education.image);
            }
            ((UniversityViewHolder) holder).item.setText(education.words);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what your suggestion in this case then

Comment: I suggest that you debug by putting  a breakpoint at `case Education.INTERNET_TYPE:` to check if this is the case.

Comment: I am getting this output Cannot cast 'activity.drawer.navigation.com.kitabsawticlone.EducationAdapter$UniversityViewHolder' to 'activity.drawer.navigation.com.kitabsawticlone.EducationAdapter.SubjectViewHolder' I have put break point already

Comment: I have added screenshot from debug mode please check it

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: @SnowdinjonEdgarjon you tried to add the screen shot editing this answer, which is not correct, instead add the screen shot editing the your question (there is an edit link also in the question).

Comment: @SnowdinjonEdgarjon I went ahead and edited the screenshot into the question for you.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery what do you think main problem

Comment: @SnowdinjonEdgarjon try what I suggest  in my edited answer